# resubscribe to the publication list - Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

Background Info :

I have created a custom unsubscribe LP. I use publication list to send the newsletter emails and this email has custom unsubscribe link . when the user clicks the link, he will be directed to the custom unsubscribe LP with a link button to unsubscribe from the particular publication lists . Once unsubscribed, a triggered email is sent to user containing RESUBSCRIBE link button option to resubscribe .

I display the values to see if they are passed correctly. From newsletter email to unsubscibe page  i gets values like below which are correct:

```
var_listname is : eDM test 2 (publication list name)
var_listid : 19121361 
key is : 68c51941-51cc-e211-827a-0050569861d9,contact
emailaddre is : ir@efc.com
var_jobid : 33119304
JobSubscriberBatchID : 1
```

When the user click the unsub link in LP, it takes it to the processign page (code) and based on it takes to confirm or error page. In processing page , i diplayed the values and they are corrrect and works fine :

```
process_listname is : eDM test 2
process_listid : 19121361
key is : 68c51941-51cc-e211-827a-0050569861d9,contact
process_unsub is : Yes
process_email is :  ir@efc.com
Status : Event posted
Error : 0
overallStatus : OK
requestId : 2c7d8a77-7733-4a4c-ac29-7ab17609b5c9
process_jid : 33119304
ts_statusMsg : Created TriggeredSend
ts_statusCode : OK
errorCode : 0
```

**Issue :**

All works till the user gets unsubscribed from the publication list  and also gets triggered email . When the user clicks the resubsciber button link in the triggered email , i get issue here . I tracked the values to see :

```
process_listname is : All Subscribers 
process_listid : 17794465 
key is : 68c51941-51cc-e211-827a-0050569861d9,contact 
process_unsub is : Sub_add_update 
process_email is : ir@efc.com
overallStatus : Error 
requestId : 3516d092-4a05-4576-b873-b83b8e3870be 
process_jid : 33115240 
re_Status : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key 
re_Error : 0 
ts_statusMsg : 
ts_statusCode : 
errorCode :
```

I wonder, here we see it gives ALL subscribers and not the particular publication lists. How can i link them and where ..is it at triggered sends ? or in the subscribe code ? so i can have user resubscribe to that particular list.

```
Triggered send  :

 SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
   SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
      SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "21406")
   SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

   SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
   SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)  
   SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)

   AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
   SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

   IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
       RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
   ENDIF

Resubscribe : 

 SET @re_subscriber = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")

    SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
    SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
    SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Value", @process_subkey)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, "Parameters", @re_lue_prop)

    SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
    SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
    SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Value", @process_listid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, "Parameters", @re_lue_prop)

    SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
    SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Value", @process_jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, "Parameters", @re_lue_prop)

     SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject('APIProperty')
SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, 'Name', 'Status')
SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, 'Value', "Active")
AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, 'Parameters', @re_lue_prop)

   SET @re_lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@re_subscriber, @overallStatus, @requestId)
    SET @re_Response = Row(@re_lue_statusCode, 1)
SET @re_Status = Field(@re_Response,"StatusMessage")
SET @re_Error = Field(@re_Response,"ErrorCode")
```

Comment: Is something not working, or are you asking us to test your code first?

Comment: I updated above. resubscribing a user from the triggered email doesn't work. needs pointers.

Comment: How is the button made, and what is the key property that's returning the null error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the resubscribe landing page a custom page for this publication? If so, you can hard code the publication list id into the the code to target the publication list you would like to re-subscribe the user to. I have used the code below for something similar:

```
SET @ll_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "SubscriberKey", @process_subkey)


set @subscription = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
//process_listid from your original email
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "ID",19121361)
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "IDSpecified", "true" )
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "Status", "Active" )
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "StatusSpecified", "true" )
AddObjectArrayItem( @ll_sub, "Lists", @subscription )

SET @ll_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @ll_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @ll_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@ll_statusMsg, 0, @ll_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
```

If the landing page is used for many publication lists you can pass the list id property value from the original email and then to the re-subscribe landing page when the button is clicked. You can declare the ID as a variable and use it in the SetObjectProperty. I have no idea how to pass a property from the original email off the top of my head but I know it is possible.

Comment: thx and it does solve part of the issue. The resubscribe LP is the custom page for the publication and Yes, the LP is used for different publications . Wonder how to pass the publication id to and from the Triggered send email to the LP ?? Should i create a new question for this? or?

Comment: It might be best to create a new question for passing the publication id. I did something similar once by passing a link id in the URL string and then using a requestParameter function to read the value in the landing page. I'm not sure it this would work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```ampscript
%%[

VAR @process_subkey, @process_listid,@process_jid, @process_batchid, @reason, @re_subscriber, @re_lue_prop, @re_lue_statusCode, @overallStatus, @requestId, @re_Response, @re_Status, @re_Error

SET @process_subkey = Attributevalue("_subscriberkey")
SET @process_jid =  Attributevalue("jobid")
SET @process_listid =  Attributevalue("listid")
SET @process_batchid =  Attributevalue("%%_jobsubscriberbatchid%%")
SET @reason = "email subscribe"

IF NOT EMPTY(@process_subkey) AND  NOT EMPTY(@process_jid) AND NOT EMPTY(@process_listid) THEN

 SET @re_subscriber = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
 SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Value", @process_subkey)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, "Parameters", @re_lue_prop)

 SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Name", "listID")
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Value", @process_listid)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, "Parameters", @re_lue_prop)

 SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Name", "jobID")
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Value", @process_jid)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, "Parameters", @re_lue_prop)
    
 SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, "Value", @process_batchid)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, "Parameters", @re_lue_prop)

 SET @re_lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@re_subscriber, @overallStatus, @requestId)

 SET @re_lue_prop = CreateObject('APIProperty')
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, 'Name', 'Status')
 SetObjectProperty(@re_lue_prop, 'Value',  "active")
 AddObjectArrayItem(@re_subscriber, 'Parameters', @re_lue_prop)
   
 SET @re_Response = Row(@re_lue_statusCode, 1)
 SET @re_Status = Field(@re_Response,"StatusMessage")
 SET @re_Error = Field(@re_Response,"ErrorCode")

 outputline(concat("status: ", @re_Status))

ELSE
  outputline(concat("NO event supported ",))

ENDIF
]%%
```

error: - value cannot be null, parameter is key. solution please

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Looking at your last line, "solution please," makes me think this is a question and not an answer. SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. If this is a question, you could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) & in it you can link to this question or its other answer for reference (just click "Share" at the bottom left of the post to get a URL). If this is an actual answer, please edit it to add an explanation as to *why* this solves the problem. "Code dump" answers are frowned upon on SFSE.