# How can we resubscribe to a publication list once an user has unsubscribed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, community

How can we resubscribe to a publication list once an user has unsubscribed from it?
The below link which has answer to the same question asked before has a piece of code which does not work and says we can hard code the publication list id into the code to target the publication list to be resubscribed.

[resubscribe to the publication list - Exacttarget](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61198/resubscribe-to-the-publication-list-exacttarget)

I was not able to get the id of the publication list anywhere in marketing cloud. Can someone please help me on where I can find the id of the publication list and also how to pass it in the code?

A sample piece of code would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: That post is from 4 years ago and likely is no longer supported.  What scale are you talking about here?  One-off changes to subscription?  Or mass changes?